# Provide string for int property in PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, propertygrid, typeconverter

Let's say I have a class with a integer property which I want to show in a PropertyGrid. Now the PropertyGrid should not simply show the integer value, but the corresponding string value from a list and further a drop down list with possible values (also as strings) for that property.

I know I have to use a TypeConverter for this and I have done this for string properties in the past. But I can't figure out how this has to be done. As you can see from my code, I'm completely helpless:

```
class MyClassConverter : TypeConverter
{
    List<string> values = new List<string>(); 

    public MyClassConverter()
    {
        values.Add("Value1");
        values.Add("Value2");
        values.Add("Value3");
    }

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        bool ret = true; //base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
        Debug.Print("CanConvertFrom: " + sourceType.ToString() + " " + ret.ToString());
        return ret;
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        bool ret = base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
        Debug.Print("CanConvertTo: " + destinationType.ToString() + " " + ret.ToString());
        return ret;
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        Debug.Print("ConvertFrom: " + value.GetType().ToString());
        //return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
        {
            if (values[i] == value)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        Debug.Print("ConvertTo: " + destinationType.ToString());
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }

    public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        Debug.Print("GetStandardValues");
        StandardValuesCollection collection = new StandardValuesCollection(values);
        return collection;
    }

    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Quickest fix would be making the property an enum type, wouldn't it?

Comment: Well not in my case. The values in the list are entered by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement `ConvertTo` with an `int` type as input (and an implicit `string` type as output, since you're talking to the property grid).

Also, if you want to support direct end user `int` input, you need also to implement `ConvertFrom` from an `int` as a `string` (like "2" for example).

Here is a piece of code that seems to work:

```
public class MyClassConverter : TypeConverter
{
    private List<string> values = new List<string>();

    public MyClassConverter()
    {
        values.Add("Value1");
        values.Add("Value2");
        values.Add("Value3");
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (value is int)
        {
            int index = (int)value;
            if (index >= 0 && index < values.Count)
                return values[index];

            return values[0]; // error, go back to first
        }
        return value;
    }

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        string s = value as string;
        if (s != null)
        {
            int index = values.IndexOf(s);
            if (index >= 0)
                return index;

            // support direct integer input & validate
            if (int.TryParse(s, out index) && index >= 0 && index < values.Count)
                return index;

            return 0; // error, go back to first
        }

        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }

    public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return new StandardValuesCollection(values);
    }

    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```